# Monitor resolution with raspberry pi 2 and NOOBS

Tags: raspberry-pi, resolution, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I got some trouble with my monitor resolution on my new pi2 with an
[Philips 284E5QHAD](http://www.philips.de/c-p/284E5QHAD_00/). The monitor can handle full hd but my pi2 seems not to do it.

Thats my basic config (/boot/config.txt)

```
#middle overclocking
arm_freq=900
core_freq=250
sdram_freq=450
over_voltage=2
# GPU RAM upgrade
gpu_mem=128
# Set sdtv mode to PAL (as used in Europe)
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=3
# Force the monitor to HDMI mode so that sound will be sent over HDMI cable
hdmi_drive=2
# Set monitor resolution
#overscan_left=0
#overscan_right=0
#overscan_top=0
#overscan_bottom=0
disable_overscan=1
```

That's the settings that I tried to use without success:

**Test1**

hdmi_group=1 | hdmi_mode=16

**Test2**

hdmi_group=2 | hdmi_mode=32

**Test3**

hdmi_group=2 | hdmi_mode=82

All with the same result.
Did someone got an idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the image and it worked with only

```
disable_overscan=1
```